# How to split a textfile at a certain character creating multiple text files

Tags: python-2.7, file, split, text-files

I have a textfile containing information about different groups and the groups are separated by a '='. I want to separate this files in two multiple text-files, for editing later.

The text-file looks like this:

```
GROUP 001
LISA ----- 134.5
ROLF ----- 122.0
NICOLAS -- 103.4
=
GROUP 002
NICOLE --- 141.1
ADAM ----- 98.2
```

And I want two separate text files (preferably called 01.txt and 02.txt) with:

```
LISA ----- 134.5
ROLF ----- 122.0
NICOLAS -- 103.4
```

And the other file

```
NICOLE --- 141.1
ADAM ----- 98.2
```

I simply tried to read the file and split it at the '=' sign, but this gives me back a list containing all the other groupinfo as an entry.

```
groups = open('input.txt').read()
groups_divided = groups.split("=\n")
print groups_divided
```

Comment: Well, isn't that wxactly what you're after? The first element contains everything before the `=` and the second everything after it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You started well, the following is one way to finish the task,

```
groups = open('input.txt').read()
groups_divided = groups.split('=\n')

for group in groups_divided:
    temp = group.split('\n')
    with open(temp[0].split()[1] + '.txt', 'w') as out:
        out.write("\n".join(temp[1:]))
```

What you got after the `groups.split('=\n')` was a list of grouped lines in the from of strings. This program processes each string-group in that list - i.e. each physical group and saves the processed version to a file.

It first splits the string-group by the newline character `'\n'` creating `temp`. It then extracts the group number for the output file name. Finally it saves all the lines in the group (stored in `temp`) except for the first one which is the `GROUP 00#` line. When saving, it joins all the saved lines with newline characters otherwise removed by `split('\n')`.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense and great explanation as well :) Much appreciated!